# OSX Yosemity Webstorm npm install -g iOS-sim

Tags: ios, node.js, npm

So I have been trying for the last 3 hours to get web storm set up on my new mac.  I'm having trouble getting the iOS-sim set up and it just gives me an error

```
Failed at the ios-sim@3.1.1 preinstall script 'rake build'.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the ios-sim package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     rake build
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls ios-sim
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
```

I've tried every google link out there and I still am at a loss.
Any thoughts?

Here is an error message I get when installing phonegap

```
Brentons-MBP:~ brentonpierce$ sudo npm install -g phonegap
Password:
npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":"0.12.3","npm":"2.7.5"})
npm WARN engine cordova-js@3.9.0: wanted: {"node":"~0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.3","npm":"2.7.5"})
npm WARN engine xmlbuilder@2.2.1: wanted: {"node":"0.8.x || 0.10.x"} (current: {"node":"0.12.3","npm":"2.7.5"})

> ws@0.4.31 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/connect-phonegap/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/engine.io/node_modules/ws > (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o
npm WARN installMany normalize-package-data was bundled with npm@1.3.4, but bundled package wasn't found in unpacked tree

> ws@0.4.31 install /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/node_modules/connect-phonegap/node_modules/socket.io/node_modules/socket.io-client/node_modules/engine.io-client/node_modules/ws > (node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)

CXX(target) Release/obj.target/bufferutil/src/bufferutil.o /usr/local/bin/phonegap -> /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap/bin/phonegap.js
phonegap@5.0.0-0.28.0 /usr/local/lib/node_modules/phonegap
├── pluralize@0.0.4
├── colors@0.6.0-1
├── semver@1.1.0
├── minimist@0.1.0
├── qrcode-terminal@0.9.4
├── shelljs@0.1.4
├── phonegap-build@0.9.1 (colors@0.6.2, qrcode-terminal@0.8.0, shelljs@0.0.9, optimist@0.3.7, phonegap-build-api@0.3.3)
├── prompt@0.2.11 (revalidator@0.1.8, pkginfo@0.3.0, read@1.0.5, winston@0.6.2, utile@0.2.1)
├── cordova@5.0.0 (underscore@1.7.0, q@1.0.1, nopt@3.0.1, cordova-lib@5.0.0)
└── connect-phonegap@0.16.0 (home-dir@0.1.2, connect-inject@0.3.2, ip@0.3.1, walkdir@0.0.8, request-progress@0.3.1, shelljs@0.2.6, http-proxy@1.8.1, request@2.33.0, tar@0.1.19, node-static@0.7.0, gaze@0.4.3, localtunnel@1.3.0, archiver@0.14.3, useragent@2.0.8, connect@2.12.0, socket.io@1.0.4)
```

Answer (score 0):

Xcode 6 is required for ios-sim to work. 
Please check that you have it installed. 
If it is installed, run it at least once.

Comment: I have xcode 6.3.2 installed, I have ran it.  Accepted the agreement.  I uninstalled phone gap cordova and ionic and re-installed them.